# How do I remove GPS data from image/video in Javascript or Node.js?

Tags: javascript, security, image-processing, amazon-s3, metadata

In my application users can upload images and videos that are publicly available - profile pictures, blog posts, etc.

Since they are publicly available to other users, then that means the metadata associated with the images is as well. This raises a huge privacy concern since info such as the user's GPS location can sometimes be determined from this metadata. I would like to strip this data out client-side and upload a new copy of the image/video without saving this data to my database (in this case S3 using presigned urls).

I have seen the library [piexifjs](https://github.com/hMatoba/piexifjs) recommended on several blogs and other StackOverflow posts. However, this library only seems to deal with JPEG type files (what about MP4 for example? and PNG now has EXIF too, as seen [here](http://ftp-osl.osuosl.org/pub/libpng/documents/pngext-1.5.0.html#C.eXIf)).

The app needs to strip out any GPS data contained in `.jpg` `.jpeg` `.png` `.gif` and `.mp4` files. I'm not concerned about other metadata. But if possible, I would like to remove all unnecessary metadata. That way I can reduce file upload size and also remove potentially malicious injected code hidden in there.

So what methods exist for doing this client side? If none exist, then how can I do this server-side?

Ideally the flow would look like this:

1. User uploads a file on the client
2. Client strips out GPS metadata
3. Client uploads stripped image to S3 via presigned url

I know that I can get the raw image data using the `FileReader` api. And so I have the following javascript code:

```
let fileNode = document.getElementById("file-uploader");

const handleUpload = () => {
    console.log("Files uploaded: ", fileNode.files[0]);
    const testFile = fileNode.files[0];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log("File Array Raw: ", fileReader.result);
        console.log("File Array Buffer: ", Buffer(fileReader.result));
    }
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(testFile);
}
```

Which outputs the raw binary and a buffer of the uploaded file successfully. But I don't know where to specificially edit the result in order to slice out the metadata.

Any help or advice is definitely recommended. My main concern is privacy and GDPR compliance.

Comment: @JaromandaX where would you suggest I ask this question then?

Comment: @JaromandaX I will add some code to my question, hopefully that will make it better

Comment: You can use the third party library `ffmpeg` . If you are using nodejs you can use `fluent-ffmpeg` 

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg`


By  you can exclude the metadata option while converting the video .

Comment: @sumit Thank you for the response, I shall check it out

Comment: @JaromandaX This question is on-topic... it's fine, except for the part about wanting to edit 4 different unrelated file types, which makes it too broad.

Comment: @the_new The key word you're looking for here is EXIF, for images.  And yes, you can absolutely do this client-side.

Comment: really? this is fine @Brad? I've seen better questions closed for being too broad :p I won't argue though

Comment: @Brad Thank you for the response. I am aware that it is called EXIF, I am just having trouble finding any info on how to edit it for files that aren't JPEG :/

Comment: Just a sidenote because you mentioned the security benefit of removing exif on the client. Please note that doing this client-side has close to zero security benefit, because an attacker would just not run your stripping code and upload whatever they want. In general you should do this server-side for security, but privacy concerns would be mitigated by doing it on the client (so you don't get to see your users' gps data). Maybe do it both then.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Yes, I completely agree that stripping the exif client-side would not prevent a user from uploading malicious data. Validation on the client and the server would be the best option then. It's for the ordinary users that I want to offer a reasonable sense of privacy protection by making sure that I am collecting as little data as necessary for the purpose of app functionality. I'm mostly concerned with GDPR compliance for those users

Comment: @the_new Did you find a solution for this?